# Configure "Send to" to copy files through MTP to specific location on smartphone?

Tags: windows-7, mtp, send-to

The Samsung Galaxy Nexus smartphone uses MTP to talk to Windows, so it's not possible to assign a drive letter to the phone.

I often have to copy files to a sub-directory on the phone, but Windows' "Send To" menu item that is displayed when right-clicking on a file copies the file at the root of the phone ("Galaxy Nexus").

Is there a way to add an item to the Send To menu to tell Windows to copy a file to a given sub-folder in the phone?

Thank you.